# Access: Combine 2 Fields in 1 with SQL Code

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to combine two field in one in my table. This shall be excecuted by clicking on a button. I thought it could work like this:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT Table.Field1 & "" & Table.Field2 AS Table.Field12"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

End Sub
```

Clearly this isn't working at all.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to update, you must use an action query, like:

```
strSQL = "Update Table Set Field12 = Field1 & Field2"
```

If you wish to select, you must a valid select query:

```
strSQL = "Select *, Field1 & Field2 AS Field12 From Table"
```

but that you cannot "execute". However, you can open it as recordset.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `UPDATE` statement, since you want to *change* values in your table:

```
UPDATE Table SET Field12 = Field1 & Field2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you can't have periods in a column alias unless you escape them.  Do either of these work?

```
strSQL = "SELECT Table.Field1 & "" & Table.Field2 AS Field12"

strSQL = "SELECT Table.Field1 & "" & Table.Field2 AS [Table.Field12]"
```